# Strategies and techniques for unit testing WinJS UI pages

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, winjs, chutzpah

I'm modifying some individual methods within existing and quite complex WinJS UI controls at the moment.

There is a lot of code within these controls which has dependencies on the contents of various `HTMLElement`s and on several other large JavaScript WinJS modules.

There are no existing unit tests for any of the methods - but I'm looking to add unit tests as I add/change functionality.

I've got a basic infrastructure for unit tests set up in VisualStudio using Jasmine and Chutzpah (similar to http://winjsby.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/windows-8-unit-tests.html)

I'm currently struggling to find a way to effectively write unit tests for these methods which:

- have so many static interdependencies (e.g. to lots of things like `WinJS.Utilities` and `msZoomTo`)
- rely so heavily on specific complex sets of elements existing in HTML.
- seem to rely on DOM event propagation and handling too

Does anyone have any suggestions or specific examples of good unit tests for large WinJS libraries, of tools to assist with setting up HTML test structures and of tools to provide mocking for static objects?